# Diagnosing timeout, connection pool or socket issue

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, ado.net, .net-6.0

I have a .Net 6 webapplication, that is hosted in IIS on Windows server 2019.

Sometimes after deployment, it will start having issues connection to SQL server and WCF services.

The thing that strikes me is that both types of errors start appearing at the same time. The SQL server, net.tcp WCF services and HTTP WCF services all start throwing these errors at the same time.

This leads me to think it could be some kind of socket exhaustion or similar?

How would I diagnose this kind of broad connection issue?

Note: The application has been ported from .Net Framework to .Net 6, and the old version does not exhibit this behavior, so I suspect that the .Net 6 code has some sort of leak, but I need to find out what is causing it.

Examples of the exceptions:

SQL error after the default 15s timeout:

> Begin failed with SQL exception Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Another sql error

> could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available] Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The wait operation timed out.

WCF net.tcp service

> The socket was aborted because an asynchronous receive from the socket did not complete within the allotted timeout of 10675199.02:48:05.4775807. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. The socket connection has been disposed.
>
> Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection'.

HTTP HTTP service

> The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. The HTTP request to 'https://www.example.com/service' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Comment: do you find the reason?

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor Not definitively. We did find that if the WCF calls were getting slower, then that could cause a surrounding SqlTransaction to hold on to a connection, causing the Sql connection pool to run out. But we did not determine why that would have any effect on regular HttpClient calls.

Being more careful with Sql connections allowed the site to survive these incidents though, and not cascade out to complete starvation.